Stripe Recurring Subscription based model giving Free Trial
I am using the below code to add products to Stripe:
const baseProduct = await stripe.products.create({
  name: 'Basetest4',
  description: 'Basetest4 subscription plan',
});

await stripe.prices.create({
  product: baseProduct.id,
  unit_amount: 800, // $8 in cents
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {
    interval: 'month',
    trial_period_days: 0, // Ensure no trial period is set
  },
});

This adds the product to Stripe. However, when I get that product on the frontend using the code:
const basePlan = products.find((product) => product.id === 'prod_R7C*********Zvw');
console.log('Base plan:', basePlan);

// const plusPlan = products.find((product) => product.name === 'Plusv2');
// console.log('Plus plan:', plusPlan);

const basePrice = prices.find((price) => price.productId === basePlan?.id);
// const plusPrice = prices.find((price) => price.productId === plusPlan?.id);

return (
  <main className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 py-12">
    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 max-w-xl mx-auto">
      <PricingCard 
        name={basePlan?.name || 'Base'} 
        price={basePrice?.unitAmount || 800} 
        interval={basePrice?.interval || 'month'} 
        trialDays={basePrice?.trialPeriodDays || 7} 
        features={['Basic Access', 'Standard Support', 'Core Features']} 
        priceId={basePrice?.id} 
      />
    </div>
  </main>
);

The code has * which is changed during running (hidden for security purposes). When I run on the frontend and click on the checkout URL,
I see this: https://imgur.com/a/NQTMpSX.
Now see there is a 14 days free trial. I don’t want to give a trial and want to start the billing from the instant the payment is made. How can I make these changes? Please let me know if you need any other code blocks.
tried adding
trial_period_days = 0


If trial_period_days is zero, trialDays={basePrice?.trialPeriodDays || 7} will output 7, because that’s what logical or does.

No, trial_period_days isn't a valid param in price creation request. Since you are using Stripe Checkout, you should check your code for checkout session creation and see if either trial_period_days or trial_end is set.
